# Fixed point of tree automorphism

Tags: graph-theory

Given the tree $T$ and its automorphism $\phi$ prove that there exists a vertex $v$ such that $\phi(v)=v$ or an edge $\{{u,v\}}$ such that $\phi(\{{u,v}\}) = \{{u,v}\}$

Comment: This would follow from the fact that the center of a tree (the set of all vertices of minimum eccentricity) is either a single vertex or two adjacent vertices. Is that theorem available?

Comment: I'd try looking at what $\phi$ does to a maximum length path $P$ in $T$. The case $\phi(P)=P$ is trivial. If $\phi(P)=P'\ne P$, then $P$ and $P'$ must intersect (maximum length paths in a graph) and I bet the fixed point or edge (as the case may be) will be in the intersection.

Comment: Yes it is bof (it is Jordan as far as i remember). Now when i think about it if a center of the tree is a single vertex or a two adjecent vericles (edge) then every isomorphism (automorphism is an isomporhism) should take one center on to another. Which finishes the proof

Comment: @bof why don't they intersect in many edges?

Comment: @IgorRivin (1) I did (do) not have a worked out proof, I was speculating on how a proof might go; that's what I was trying to convey with the words "I'd try". (2) I bet the fixed point or edge would be *in* the intersection of those two maximum paths. Of course that intersection could be a long path; I didn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_tree) The center is preserved by any automorphism. There is also the *baricenter* of a tree (which is a vertex for which the sum of the distances to the other points is minimized). Again, there is either one such or two adjacent ones. Are the center and the baricenter the same? For you to find out.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a sketch. First show that $\phi$ maps leaves to leaves (leaves are vertices of degree 1). Now, let $T=T_0$, and let $L_i$ be the set of leaves of $T_i$. Consider the graph $T_1=T_0-L_0$. Show that $T_1$ is a tree. Show that if you repeat this process you will end up with either an isolated vertex or a single edge. This vertex or edge is a fixed point.